# Is there other proof of Pascal Points on the sides of the quadrilateral theorem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, projective-geometry, quadrilateral

Theorem [source1](http://dx.doi.org/10.18642/jmsaa_7100121666), [source2](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2017volume17/FG201748.pdf):

*Let there be: a convex quadrilateral; a circle that intersects a pair of opposite sides of the quadrilateral, that passes through the point of intersection of the extensions of these sides, and that passes through the point of intersection of the diagonals.
In addition, let there be four straight lines, each of which passes both through the point of intersection of the circle with a side of the quadrilateral and through the point of intersection of the circle with the extension of a diagonal.
Then there holds: the straight lines intersect at two points that are located on the other pair of opposite sides of the quadrilateral.*

Is there other proof of that theorem? Without using Pascal theorem.